# rsvg-convert svg to pdf bad image quality

Tags: pdf, svg

I've modified some old electrical plans with Inkscape who are scanned. Now I have to re-convert them into PDF format, then merge them to the original document.

The problem is that, with Inkscape, I get some issues on the document, like unexpected rectangles with shade.

When I convert it with rsvg-convert, raster images are compressed with a poor quality, but they are already bad so the result is not good . I use the following command :

```
rsvg-convert --keep-image-data -a -f pdf 2.svg > out.pdf
```

And I get the result at right :
[image: original vs converted]

Finally, with imagemagick, everything is rastered, even added texts and elements and quality is bad too.

How can I solve this problem, I think the best is rsvg-convert, but for the moment it's not good enough for me...

Thank by advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I found a [method](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/rsvg-convert.1.html) to increase the resolution of the output.

Options for `rsvg-convert` (from the manual page)

```
 -d --dpi-x number
              Set the X resolution of the image in pixels per inch.  RSVG's current default is 90
              DPI.

-p --dpi-y number
              Set the Y resolution of the image in pixels per inch.  RSVG's current default is 90
              DPI.
```

Try `rsvg-convert --keep-image-data -d 300 -p 300 -a -f pdf 2.svg > out.pdf`, which will set the x resolution and y resolution of the image as 300 pixels per inch.